# stuck at the datepicker function as it is not giving the date in the ejs file

Tags: javascript

This is my ejs file:

```js
<div class="d-block text-muted">
  <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
  <%if(t.Due_Date==null){%>
    <%="No Deadline"%> <%}else{%> <%=t.Due_Date%> <%}%>
</div>
```

And this is my date handler function in a `script.js` file:

```js
//date handler function
for(let date of document.querySelectorAll('.text-muted')){
    
  date.innerText = date.innerText.toString().substring(0, 10);
  console.log(date.innerText);
}
```

When I add a todo list in place of the date, only "No DeadLine" is printing. How can I resolve this problem?

when iam adding a ToDO list in place of date only "No DeadLine" is printing...how can i resolve this problem?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//date handler function
for(let date of document.querySelectorAll('.text-muted')){
    if(date.innerText.trim() !== "No Deadline"){
        date.innerText = date.innerText.toString().substring(0, 10);
    }
    console.log(date.innerText);
}
```

This code checks if the trimmed inner text of the element is not equal to "No Deadline". If it's not, it extracts the first 10 characters of the inner text as before. Otherwise, it leaves the text as is.

Comment: this code is still printing "No DeadLine" after i selected the date......

Comment: interesting, two things, I can possibly try, 

1.You can modify the date handler function to only remove text after the first 10 characters if the text length is greater than 10. 
date.innerText.length > 10

2. you can try using the textContent property instead of innerText, as it updates the text content of an element regardless of its formatting.

Comment: both the things are not working....if u have any other method it would be helpful for me...